# file copied using PHP or Windows Explorer has stale Date Created time stamp

Tags: php, windows

When copying a file using PHP like so:

```
$result = copy(
    'C:\xampp\htdocs\MISCELLANEOUS\Test\FilesAndFolders.php',
    'C:\xampp\htdocs\MISCELLANEOUS\Test\backups\FilesAndFolders_version1.php'
);
echo $result;
```

The file's Date Created time stamp correctly reflects the time when the file gets copied initially.  However, if the copied file is deleted and the copy operation is performed again using the exact same name for the backup file, the Date Created reflects the time when the file was copied the first time instead of subsequent times.

For instance, when ...backups\FilesAndFolders_version1.php was first created that file had a Date Created of 8/26/2016 8:36 PM.  After deleting that file and trying to copy it again at 9:03 PM, the file's Date Created still said 8/26/2016 8:36 PM (the time portion should have been 9:03 PM).  Why isn't the time  updating to the actual time of the subsequent copy operation?  Is there a way to force it to update?

**Additional Information**
Even after a system reboot this behavior is the same - the time stamp will not update.  Machine's OS is Windows 7.

Doing copy/paste from Windows Explorer exhibited the same behavior.  That ruled out there being a problem with the PHP code.  Deleting the 'backups' folder then recreating it allowed the copied file's Date Created to be updated the first time the file was copied but not subsequent copy operations after the backed up file was deleted.

It was possible to reproduce this behavior on a different Windows 7 PC.

Comment: Are you certain it's not just always reflecting the creation date of the original file you're copying?

Comment: Yes, I'm certain because when the target file name is changed to `'C:\xampp\htdocs\MISCELLANEOUS\Test\backups\FilesAndFolders_version2.php'` then the Date Created of the file accurately reflects the date and time the file was copied using the new target name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is associated with the file system, not PHP, and it is actually deliberate.  It's called "file system tunneling" and it's possible to disable the behavior.  See this link for more detail:
https://superuser.com/questions/715536/wrong-date-created-for-files-in-windows-when-copying-files-if-the-file-has-alre